# Troubleshooting Ubuntu via remote terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh, reboot, log

> In a situation where an unscheduled system reboot occurred on an Ubuntu environment and the only way to access the device is via Remote Terminal.
>
> > 1. What are some of the things you would look at to determine the root of the issue?
> > 2. If the Reboot was related to an application failure, how would I know?
> > 3. What are some of the things to investigate in the case of an application issue?

This is a sort of homework question I've been asked for a job interview and I wanted to know if I was on the right track. Though an answer is appreciated, I'd prefer maybe just hints on what commands or processes to research as I'd like to learn how to do this for myself. Here's what I have so far:

**Access Ubuntu with SSH:**

```
ssh remote_username@remote_host //(i.e: ssh john@10.0.2.24)
```

**Investigate System Logs**

```
sudo cat /var/log/*.log
```

Or use tail to get only the last couple lines in a given log

```
sudo tail var/log/*.log
```

Could I simply look at just 'syslog'(syslogd) for something that happened before the reboot occurred? Is checking the kernel ring with 'dmesg' recommended?

**Application Crash Check**

This is sort of where I'm stuck. I get the feeling I'd need to use Apport to debug the application that's causing the crash (answering question #3), but I don't know how to figure out what application would be causing the crash.

Answer (score 2):

I might be over thinking the problem. I just need to read the crash logs in `/var/crash` and `/var/log/`. If I am doing this remotely and want to keep a record of the logs, I can just copy them to a folder on the machine I'm running the secure shell on using `scp`.

```
scp /var/crash/*.crash [username]@[host]:Desktop/crash_report.txt
```